# Counter inside for-each loop xslt

Tags: xslt, foreach, counter

I have some xml code like:

```
<b>
   <A a="1"/>
   <A a="2"/>
   <A a="1"/>
</b>
```

and i want to count the number of elements A that have as value of a, 1
So i have tried with a

for-each A
 count(@a=1)

but it doesn't work ...

Somebody knows how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: I would rather look at it from another perspective. You may not even need a `for-each` loop at all... Why not using something like `count(//A[@a=1])`?

Comment: Never say "it doesn't work". Tell us how it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `@a=1` is a boolean. A boolean is a singleton, ie. a sequence of length 1, so count() applied to a boolean returns 1.

To count the number of nodes in a node-set, use `count(X)` where X is an expression that returns the node-set: here `count(/b/A[@a='1'])`.